# How to create google hangout group with mcabber?

Tags: jabber

How can I create (or just join) a google hangout group using [mcabber](https://mcabber.com/)?

[mcabber](https://mcabber.com/) does support MUC (Multi-User Chat) so it should be possible. I have it working on a non-google based XMPP server.